# Why android project output is different in Android emulator and Hardware device

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-emulator

When I run my android project in **android emulator** (Nexus 5X) it shows the correct layout which I have designed. but if I run the project in **Hardware device**( Samsung Galaxy J2 Prime) it shows different output.(margins are not exactly correct In Hardware device it's stick to the bottom, **see the margins at bottom**) 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkB5E.jpg) - Hardware device's output
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYHR8.jpg) - Emulator's output

And this is the xml code of layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".OrderStatus">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listOrders"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="550dp">


        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listCalls"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">


        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It can be due to pixel density on device and emulator.

Comment: So if I develop android application with android studio,is it not fit to all android devices? Should I use different formattings for different devices?

Comment: Yes and No. You can Configure your UI and also there is options to make layout for different display. Use ConstraintLayout instead of linear or relative. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work do the things below:

- Change the size type of recyclerView from **dp** (density pixels) to **sp** (scalable pixel)

  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/background"
      tools:context=".OrderStatus">

  ```
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/listOrders"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="550sp">


      </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/listCalls"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="100sp">


      </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


  </LinearLayout>
  ```

This change in scaling of the layout also varies from device to device.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have coordinated layouts in different devices, don't use dp sizes. It depends to size of phone. It's better to use constraint layout. See my answer for this question as an example for using constraint layout: [How to prevent one activity from resizing when keyboard opens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61095575/how-to-prevent-one-activity-from-resizing-when-keyboard-opens/61095703#61095703)